# Windows 2012r2 RDS: after installing desktop experience icons are english not german

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, rds

I installed the desktop experience on a 2012r2 RDS Session Host. 
Now the default windows icons on start menu like `computer` `Control Panel` or `Administrative Tools` are now in english. 
 But the rest of the OS is still german, only windows tools in start menu.

How can I fix that??

Comment: Were you able to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings
```

and change "`Override for Windows display language`" to `german` (Whatever you want) and reboot

[image]

```
Source
```

https://blog.contabo.com/tutorials/changing-display-language-windows-server-2012/
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825705.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Well this didn't fix the issue, I had to rename the shortcuts.